# Dynamic directive templates using app level resolve AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, local-storage

Currently i am implementing a completely stateless token-based authentication with AngularJS and a REST API as backend service. This works pretty well, but about one state i am currently not aware of and wanted to ask you how to handle it.

My intend is only to save my authentication token in the local storage from the client. On initial loading from the application i want to retrieve all user information from the REST API (GET /me) and save it in the $scope from my AngularJS project.

After implementing it, i have several problems to be sure that the retrieved user information are completely resolved and could work with the informations (like the access rights from the user).

I just want you to show an example where i ran into a kind of "asynchronous problem".

```
angular.directive('myDirective', ['MyAsyncService', function(MyAsyncService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: function(element, attributes) {
      console.log(MyAsyncService.getData());
    } 
  }
}]
```

At this example my asynchronous service haven't the information yet, when the directive is rendered. Also retrieve the async data in the resolve function from ngRoute/ui-router or in the run() method from AngularJS couldn't solve my problem.

So back to my question ... It is better to save some information from the user on client side to avoid some of this problems? From my point of view it would be better not to save any kind of user information (like access rights, username, id, email address, ...) due security purposes.

How you handle you the authentication and authorization in a token-based AngularJS application?

Thanks in advance, hopefully you can get me back on track.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. If you could explain a little more!

Comment: I will try to explain my intend in a detailed way. After login my user in my AngularJS application i save the token, which is generated from my REST API service, in the local storage from the client.

Afterwards i can fetch all user information via my API endpoint /me - this works like expected. The problem is, that i don't want to save any user information except the authentication token in the local storage from the client. So after bootstrapping my application i call the /me endpoint and save the response (the full user object) in my scope.

Comment: The problem is, that this asynchronous call is executed after my angularjs directives are rendered yet. But in my directives i need some information from the user object (which i save in the scope) like the accessRoles but logically i get an undefined when i try to get some information from $scope.user because the asynchronous call is finished yet. Hopefully it could be clear up your view. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `resolve()` authentication - especially this type of authentication at the app level.

If you aren't using [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) - take a look.

When we `resolve()` on a route what we are saying is - *do not do anything else until this thing is finished doing what it's doing.*

This also assumes you are familiar with *promises*.

Your resolve dependency will ultimately expect that this asynchronous request is returning a promise so that it may chain controller logic after the callback finishes execution.

For example:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('myState', {
    resolve:{
      auth:  function($http){
        // $http returns a promise for the url data
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/myauth'});
      }
    },
    controller: function($scope, auth){
      $scope.simple = auth;
    }
});
```

But there's more. If you want the resolve to happen at the begining of application execution for *any* route - you also need to chain your state declarations:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/views/app.tpl.html',
    resolve:{
      auth:  function($http){
        // $http returns a promise for the url data
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/myauth'});
      }
    },
    controller: function($scope, auth){
      $scope.resolvedauth = auth;
    }
  }
  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home/views/home.tpl.html',
    controller: function($scope){
      //Should be available.
      console.log($scope.$parent.resolvedauth);
    }
  });
```

Now that your children inherit from the app level resolve, you could control the template by doing something like this:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
      return 'myDirective.'+attr.auth+'.html';
    }
  };
});
```

And the declaration itself:

```
<my-directive auth="resolvedauth.status" />
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution and especially this way i currently using yet. The problem is that the directive is rendered anyway, even if the resolve function from ui-router/ngRoute is resolved.

Depending on the user state i want to force my directive to show another template. The problem is that, on executing the "templateUrl" function of the directive the async authentication call isn't finished. I could solve this problem, when i use only one template and control the template with "ng-show" but i think this isn't the clean way... you know what i mean?

Comment: Could you understand my intend? Perhaps it is possible that i can solve it with a HTTP Interceptor on each request, to check if the user is authenticated and if yes, retrieve the user object and continue with executing the bootstrapping. Then my directives should be rendered after my user object is available in the $rootScope

Comment: Good example.  I do want to point out that the referencing of the resolvedauth with $scope.$parent is unnecessary since scopes use prototypical inheritance.  You can just as easily use $scope.resolvedauth.

Comment: All my application routes inherit from my base route where the authentication is resolved. So basically my intend isn't possible? I am thinking about a solution to authenticate outside from my angular app and in the bootstrapping process injecting the user object/service - it is a mess..

Comment: @kmkemp Thanks for pointing that out - feel free to make edits.

Comment: @DanKanze Thank you! The difference between your and my current implementation was, that you pass the resolved object as variable in the directive and then you could solve my problem. Thank you and all others for your hints!